# Events & Refs in a stateless functional component filled from a map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have several lists of things in my state. such that:

```
this.state = {
    [
        list1: [
                item1: value1,
                item2: value2,
            ]
        list2: [
                item1: value1,
                item2: value2,
            ]
    ]
}
```

I am attempting to create a re-usable stateless functional component that will create list items with a removal button,  and either iterate the lists, or iterate the keys depending on the information I loop with the map function, such that:

```
this.state.list1.map(item => <Component props={item} method={removeItem} />)
```

will output list items something like this:

```
<li> value1 <button onClick={removeitem} ref={item1} >Click to remove</button></li>
<li> value2 <button onClick={removeitem} ref={item2} >Click to remove</button></li>
```

so my questions are the following:

Do I need to put keys on both the component in the method on the parent that I will use to generate the final outputs And in the children?
will the stateless functional component's children accept a ref?  if not, how can I reference the correct data in the onClick function so that it gets removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stateless functional components do not have backing instances so `ref`s are not possible.

You can pass the `index` of the item into the component:

```
this.state.list1.map((item, index) => <Component props={item} method={() => { this.removeItem(index); }} />)
```

Comment: If you want onClick, make sure "method" is written as "onClick" when writing your code. Then you may write